# About listing the observers for a specific object

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

1. Is there a way to know which is the list of observers for a specific instance ?
2. How am I suppose to use [observationInfo](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueObserving_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/observationInfo), could you provide an example ?

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a write-up of how to use observationInfo in "Technical Note TN2124: Mac OS X Debugging Magic." The idea is that you can use it in the debugger to discover the information you need.

Not only that, but I tried using it like this:

```
id what = [self observationInfo];
NSLog(@"%@", [what description]);
```

and this is what I got in the log:

```
    <NSKeyValueObservationInfo 0x7fdb8953c380> (
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x7fdb8953c270: Observer: 0x7fdb8953bf60, Key path: subscribed, Options: <New: NO, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x0, Property: 0x7fdb8953c350>
)
```

('subscribed' is an ivar in one of my own objects)

There doesn't appear to be a public interface either for NSKeyValueObservationInfo or NSKeyValueObservance.

It appears I got the benefit of learning something new from your question!